# Inexplicable bugs in Unity iOS build

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

So my Android build is fine and good to go. It has been for a while. I bought a cheap Macbook (Air 2015 i7 8GB Mojave) and zipped the project file on my PC, unzipped on the Mac, set as iOS build within Unity. Everything works fine in play mode within the editor on the Mac.

I then tried to build to Xcode... Sorted the Certificates/team stuff etc. Initially it wouldn't build at all but after some Googling someone said to untick "Strip engine code" within Optimization of Player Settings in Unity which I did and since then it builds to Xcode and also to the iPhone I have for testing (iPhone SE - 11.4.1).

But there are a few bugs with the game when playing, several of which I think I can fix (glitchy movement, layers misbehaving etc). But the main problem is that the Game Over scene doesn't load. The game just shuts down or freezes when the player loses. It is only a simple 3 scene game, kind of like Flappy Bird so I don't know why the game scene runs fine but the game over scene (only showing the score) doesn't.

And when I look at xcode to try and figure it out, I don't really know what I am looking at.

When I first press build in Xcode I get 8 warnings, which after research, I believe probably are not the problem... But one stands out to me as potentially an issue: "This file is set to build for a version older than the deployment target. Functionality may be limited [9]"

But I can't win regarding versions. If its talking about Unity versions... My PC version of Unity is 2019.1.0f2 which I haven't been able to find for the Macbook. The only 2019 versions I have been able to install are 2019.2.0f1 and 2019.1.13f1 and I have tried opening the build in both installs and a pop up says "Do you want to upgrade your Project to a newer version of Unity?". I have also tried 2018.4.5f1 on the Mac and in that case the pop up says "Do you want to downgrade to an older version of Unity". So I have to use one of them.

And if its talking about iOS versions. Regarding the iPhone, even though it is running iOS 11.4.1. In the Project Navigator I am leaving the "Deployment Target" setting at 9.0 which if I understand correctly should mean that anything newer should run? But even so, I have tried changing that setting to 11.4 (and 11.4.1) and I still get the "This file is set to build for a version older than the deployment target. Functionality may be limited" error.

Other than the "version error" potentially being the issue... In the "Show the debug navigator" tab I get the following highlighted in red: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Could that be the main problem causing the freezing/closing on game over? After some research, apparently that could be something to do with a null reference error? But I don't really know what to do with that information?

Like I said initially, I don't really know what I am looking at regarding xcode. Or how to use it. Any tutorials I have seen regarding Unity and xcode, their builds go smoothly with no major issues.

Is there anything else in xcode I should be doing/looking at?

Comment: Have you tried [this tutorial](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/building-for-mobile#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b4a1)?  Also you are using zip files rather than source control?  Bad idea; look into git and create a private repo on github and then you can have a branch per platform for example.

Comment: Thanks I hadn't found that tutorial! I will start fresh using that and see what I can do. Someone else on another forum recommended github so I can switch machines easily. I will look into that. Thanks again!